# Pass value from Angular 5 to Java REST API using http put, line 0:-1 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>

Tags: java, jersey, angular5

I'm facing an issue to try learn the full cycle of web following of data, i passed value from java jersay REST-API to angular 5, but i wanna pass text from angular to backend to execute some query and return the result again, i got confused between @FormParam and many things,

bellow my code,

> File-list.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FileList } from './file-list';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
save(fileList: FileList): Observable<Response> {

console.log('Saving person ' + JSON.stringify(fileList));
return this.http.put('http://localhost:8080/SWBackend/jaxrs/Person/Save', JSON.stringify(fileList), { headers: this.getHeaders()});}
```

> List.component.html

```
<form (click)="save()" method="POST" action="http://localhost:8080/SWBackend/jaxrs/Person/Save">
    <p>
        Path : <input type="text" name="pathUrl" />
    </p>
    Press to show the files
    <input type="submit" value="Add User" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
</form>
```

> Java file.java

```
@PUT
@Path("Save")
@Consumes({ "application/xml", "application/json" })
@Produces("application/json")
public Response saveEmp(FilesList pathUrl) {
    System.out.println("Reach Save Emp");
    return Response.ok().header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();
}
```

i'm getting this error:

> line 0:-1 no viable alternative at input ''

i don't know if my way is right or no, but i was trying since week ago,

thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead,

in your form remove this:

```
<form (click)="save()" method="POST" action="http://localhost:8080/SWBackend/jaxrs/Person/Save">
```

Use ReactiveFormsModule for your forms, using FormGroup and FormControl.

Then in your component, when you submit the form, it will invoke the function to call your service which in return will communicate with your java controller.

The Component should have the function that is associated with your formGroup in your template(html).

The function should then call your service such as: this.service.save(fileList);

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

ex:

```
<form [formGroup]="fileListForm" (ngSubmit)="save(fileListForm.value)">
    <input type="text" formControlName="fileListNameControl">
</form>
```

Component:

```
private fileListForm: FormGroup;
private fileListNameControl: FormControl;

 ngOninit(){
   this.fileListForm = new FormGroup({
    fileListNameControl: new FormControl("", Validators.required)
   });
 }



save(form: any){
 // get your form values here and then call service
  this.fileLIstService.save('your value');
}
```

** Make sure to import ReactiveFormsModule via @angular/forms in your module.

Comment: i tried your solution but i think i didn't applied it well, i tried another solution it give me 400 status but line 0:-1 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>' is still appearing, any other solutions?